# Gremlin query to retrieve count and data in the same response

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am looking for help with an efficient gremlin query which returns data in the expected format.

**Data structure :**

```
g.V('user').property('id','1').property('name','name 1').property('city','city1')
g.V('user').property('id','2').property('name','name 2').property('city','city2')
g.V('user').property('id','3').property('name','name 3').property('city','city3')
g.V('user').property('id','4').property('name','name 4').property('city','city4')
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
  "count" : 4,
  "users : [
     { 
       "id" : "1",
       "name" : "name 1"
     },
     { 
       "id" : "2",
       "name" : "name 2"
     },
     { 
       "id" : "3",
       "name" : "name 3"
     },
     { 
       "id" : "4",
       "name" : "name 4"
     }
  ]
 }
```

Any help with the query is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
g.V().hasLabel('user')
.project('id', 'name').by(id()).by(values('name')).fold()
.project('count', 'users').by(count(local)).by()
```

Comment: Thanks but `elementMap` isn't supported in Cosmos DB Gremlin API yet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support

Comment: So you can use ````valueMap(true)```` or ````valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens)```` which ever supported

Comment: `valueMap` is working. But response has all properties from `user` vertex.  I want only `id` and `name` properties in the response json.

Comment: I updated the question with correct data structure.

Comment: You can run ````valueMap(true, 'name')```` that way you will get id,label and name. Or you can use ````project```` (I updated the answer)